# Z3: can Z3 tells me if arithmetic operations return concrete value?

Tags: python, z3

I have a simple code like below:

```
a, b, c = BitVecs('a b c', 32)
a == b + c
c == b + 5
```

We can easily see that (c - b) returns a concrete value (number 5), but (a - b) returns something abstract (because a - b == c, which has unknown value).

The question is: given an arithmetic operation like above case, can Z3 tells us that the result is concrete, or not? If this is possible, how to do that?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z3 is a theorem prover, but we can also see it as a constraint solver. We can view expressions such as `a == b + c` as constraints. The Z3 Python interface has a command called `solve`. It tries to solve a set of constraints. That it, it tries to find an "assignment" that will make all constraints true. For example, if we execute the following commands (also available [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/3p8o)).

```
a, b, c = BitVecs('a b c', 32)
solve(a == b + c, c == b + 5)
```

It produces the solution:

```
[b = 0, a = 5, c = 5]
```

We say the solution "satisfies" the constraints. 
Z3 has several other commands and APIs. 
For more information about Z3, see the [online tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/guide).

Comment: Leo, thanks. Actually what I wanted is to verify if c always has the same concrete value of 5. I came up with a simple solution: find a model of c, then add to the solver another constraint (such as c != 5) to see if there is any conflict. If there is, then c always has the constant value of 5.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it.

Comment: This leas to another question: How can we use Z3 to generate the "opposite" constraint automatically? For ex, opposite of "c == 5" is "c != 5", or opposite of "a > b" is "a <= b". If this is possible, how to generate the "opposite" constraint? (I "invented" the "opposite" term here, not sure what they call in literature)

Comment: We can use `Not(c)` for creating a Z3 expression that is equivalent to the "opposite" of `c`. Examples: `Not(c ==5)`, `Not(a > b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I found this question old. I want to post my solution to find if some value is concrete in z3.

The following methods test if a bitvector has concrete value by testing it always equals or not equals to a concrete value (zero). Simplify is "required" before calling `is_true` or `is_false`.

```
bool is_concrete_byte(z3::expr byte) {

    z3::expr zero = context.bv_const(0, 8);

    return (zero == byte).simplify().is_true() ||
            (zero == byte).simplify().is_false();

}
```